# Paste a excel formula in the same cell in different workseets to return the worksheet name

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to get sheet name in cell C2 in every worksheet in an excel workbook. I am using the formula,

```
=RIGHT(CELL("filename"),LEN(CELL("filename"))-FIND("]",CELL("filename")))
```

This formula does work and give the sheet name. However, when i hold down ctrl and shift and select all the worksheets to reflect this formula, C2 cell in every sheet only has the same sheet name.

Is there a different way to paste this formula so that each of the cell shows its respective sheet name?

Comment: That is because the formula is not referencing to one of the cells in respective sheets specifically, so when you are excluding the last param i.e. `[reference]` by default it takes the sheet cell reference where you hit the enter, like if you use this for now it would work as expected: `=RIGHT(CELL("filename",A1),LEN(CELL("filename",A1))-FIND("]",CELL("filename",A1)))` or `=TEXTAFTER(CELL("filename",A1),"]")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or, alternatively could use <kbd>TEXTAFTER()</kbd> (**`MS365`** ***Exclusive***)

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>C2</kbd>

```
=TEXTAFTER(CELL("filename",A1),"]")
```

---

Reasons for not working I have sighted above in comments:

> *That is because the formula is not referencing to one of the cells in*
> *respective sheets specifically, so when you are excluding the last*
> *param i.e. [reference] by default it takes the sheet cell reference*
> *where you hit the enter, like if you use this for now it would work as*
> *expected.*